# Countdown timer notification scheduling logic - Swift 3

Tags: ios, timer, notifications, swift3, countdown

My timer starts at 5:00 and counts down to 0. When it hits 0, it resets back to five minutes. Assume that my app terminates when the timer hits 3:00. I send notifications to the user notifying them of the time remaining every minute. So after the timer begins, the user is sent a local notification that says: "Four minutes remaining." How do I accurately schedule the notification that will say: "Two minutes remaining" and "one minute remaining"?

I can set a non-repeating notification that fires after three minutes pass and that works fine. If it repeats, it fires too soon the second time.

I can set a repeating notification that fires after 480 seconds or eight minutes. But it fires too late the second time.

That's all I can come up with.

How can I schedule this notification correctly?

I'd be happy to provide more details/information/code.